# Is it mandatory to write session.update(emploee) while updating record in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it mandatory to write `session.update(employee)` while updating record in hibernate?

Here is my code.

```
public void updateEmployee() {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Employee employee = (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, 113);
        employee.setName("Prakash1");
        employee.setSal(60008);
        //session.update(employee);
        transaction.commit();
        System.out.println("Employee records updated!");
    } catch (HibernateException e) {

        transaction.rollback();

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        session.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: No. It's completely useless, and usually is a sign that the programmer didn't understand how Hibernate works, and what the update() method does.

Comment: then what is the use of update method?

Comment: To take a detached instance, and attach it to the session, with new state. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-detach-reattach. You should almost never do that. BTW, the standard JPA API, which you should prefer, doesn't even have such a method.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the reply.. We can directly write transaction.commit() without session.update().. It is working fine. I checked it.

Comment: Is there any way to fail the updating record in db with this process?

Comment: Just like everything else:rollback the transaction.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand the previous comment. can u elaborate it clearly?

Comment: If you want an update to not actually happen, you rollback the transaction. Not sure how I can explain it in another way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..